# AJAX update div without creating partial

Tags: ajax, octobercms

I have some page:

```
title = "page"
url = "/page"
layout = "default"
==
function onTest()
{
    $this['result'] = 'Test string';
}
==

<!-- AJAX enabled form -->
<form data-request="onTest" data-request-update="mypartial: '#myDiv'"></form>

<!-- Result container -->
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

After submitting the form I can get 'result' variable only in partial 'mypartial', where code is: `Here  is {{ result }}`. And this code inserts into #myDiv.

How can I get 'result' variable without creating partial? Why should I create .htm file (partial) for each little AJAX query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can easily update your div with id `myDiv` from server side.

> You just need to push markup with proper id `#myDiv` it will update that `Html Element with given ID` automatically. [ **we do not need to ask for partial or need partial** ]

```
title = "page"
url = "/page"
layout = "default"
==
<?php
function onTest()
{
    $result = 'Test string';    
    return ['#myDiv' => 'New Result: ' . $result]; 
}
?>
==
<!-- AJAX enabled form -->
<form data-request="onTest">
    <button type="submit">Submit Fire Ajax</button>
</form>

<!-- Result container -->
<div id="myDiv">old result</div>
```

> After `successful Ajax` request markup for `myDiv` will be

```
<div id="myDiv">New Result: Test string</div>
```

> Good thing is you do not need to write javascript to update `myDiv` as part of October Ajax framework it will automatically search `#myDiv` and update its markup.

**When you return an Array for an Ajax api of October Cms**

```
return ['#myDiv' => 'Hello'];
```

At client side it will automatically search element with id `myDiv` and if it found it, It will update it with given markup on successful Ajax request, for this example its `Hello`

If any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I needed.

Comment: Can you give me a suggestion that how can I auto update a partial after change occur in database
(i-e new comment or new message) to display like live chat, 
I do't want to use pushers and web-sockets, I want to do it some octoberCMS way....

Comment: I don't think there is any way of doing it as you can see client things are client side they don't know anything what is happening on server, until they refresh page or fire ajax. as you mentioned earlier you don't want to use any pusher or socket best would be you fire ajax request every 5 sec. or so its not highly suggestible as its really bad practice. but there is no other option i guess :(