# OctoberCMS Form not submiting (AJAX handler not found)

Tags: ajax, laravel, octobercms, october-form-controller

I created a component inside my plugin directory and in default.htm i put my form html and include my component in my partial. But when i when i submit form i'm getting "AjaxHandler Component:onSend was not found"

default.htm

```
<div class="filter-holder">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
 <form name="contact-form" data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onSend" data-request-success="alert('Message Sent')">

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" name="agent" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">

                    <select class="form-control" id="services" name="services[]">&nbsp;
                        {% for client in records %}
                            <option value="{{ client.service }}">{{ client.service }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select class="form-control" id="search" name="area[]">&nbsp;
                        {% for client in records %}
                            <option value="{{ client.area }}">{{ client.area }} Miles</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Agents" class="red-btn btn btn-default">
                    <a class="location-view" href="#">location</a></div>
            </form>

ComponentClass.php

class MarkerData extends ComponentBase {

    public function componentDetails() {
        return [
            'name' => 'Marker Data',
            'description' => 'List of marker data'
        ];
    }


    public function onSend()
    {
       $data = post();
       print_r($data);die;
    }}
```

and In my partial file i included component

{% component "MarkerData" %}

```
Partial Code:

description = "A quick way to reference testimonials in the theme."

[viewBag]
snippetCode = "location-form"
snippetName = "Locations"
snippetProperties[category][title] = "Select Category"
snippetProperties[category][type] = "dropdown"
snippetProperties[category][default] = "customer"
snippetProperties[category][options][customer] = "Customer"
snippetProperties[category][options][agent] = "Agent"

[builderList]
modelClass = "Tech\Locations\Models\Location"
scope = "-"
scopeValue = "{{ :scope }}"
displayColumn = "name"
noRecordsMessage = "No records found"
detailsPage = "-"
detailsUrlParameter = "id"
pageNumber = "{{ :page }}"

[MarkerData]
==
{% set records = builderList.records %}
{% set displayColumn = builderList.displayColumn %}
{% set noRecordsMessage = builderList.noRecordsMessage %}
{% set detailsPage = builderList.detailsPage %}
{% set detailsKeyColumn = builderList.detailsKeyColumn %}
{% set detailsUrlParameter = builderList.detailsUrlParameter %}
{% component "MarkerData" %}
```

I want my form to hit the method defined in component. Is there any other way to submit form via ajax in OctoberCMS

Comment: your form code is not complete can you put whole partial code.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya Added.

Comment: your `default.htm` code is broken i guess from top, talking about that :)

Comment: Yes i edit it also. It only has html. :)

Comment: hmm are you sure you included `{% component "MarkerData" %}` in your partial as i see you included `{% component "LocationData" %}` but not the `markerdata`

Comment: may be that is issue ?

Comment: No i change the name while uploading. I'm getting ajax handler not found. when i submit the form

Comment: @HardikSatasiya what is the proper way to run ajax call when i press submit button and render the response on same page but in different div id

Comment: you can check my answer here this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675304/ajax-update-div-without-creating-partial/53680861#53680861

Answer (score 0):

In your partial code you need to add

> Partial Code:

```
[viewBag]
snippetCode = "location-form"
snippetName = "Locations"
snippetProperties[category][title] = "Select Category"
snippetProperties[category][type] = "dropdown"
snippetProperties[category][default] = "customer"
snippetProperties[category][options][customer] = "Customer"
snippetProperties[category][options][agent] = "Agent"

[builderList]
modelClass = "Tech\Locations\Models\Location"
scope = "-"
scopeValue = "{{ :scope }}"
displayColumn = "name"
noRecordsMessage = "No records found"
detailsPage = "-"
detailsUrlParameter = "id"
pageNumber = "{{ :page }}"

[LocationData] <======= I guess this is not needed
[MarkerData] <========= This ONE you need add
==
{% set records = builderList.records %}
{% set displayColumn = builderList.displayColumn %}
{% set noRecordsMessage = builderList.noRecordsMessage %}
{% set detailsPage = builderList.detailsPage %}
{% set detailsKeyColumn = builderList.detailsKeyColumn %}
{% set detailsUrlParameter = builderList.detailsUrlParameter %}
{% component "MarkerData" %}
```

after that it will add `MarkerData` to that page so `OctoberCMS` can find `that component and its Ajax-handler`

if any b\doubt please comment.

Comment: Still there is error when submitting "Ajaxhandler onSend not found". i've method in my component file onSend.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved. I forget to add component in content layout from backend

Comment: so it means now you included component twice. one in layout and one in a partial ???

Comment: @Zakirhussain Yes

Comment: @rameez.hashmi I think in my answer i also suggested same to add that component.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya i thought you were saying to add component to partial

Comment: @rameez.hashmi if you are not using component anywhere else for this partial then it would be wise to add it in `partial` as `layout included in other pages as well`. if you need that component used in pages where this layout added then its wise to add it in `layout`. - so it depends on you where to add it. according to your answer it suited to add it in partial. - as i do not have more info about your structure so. but missing items was that to add it :)

Answer (score 0):

{% framework extras %}

is required if you are using partial put this in partials.

This is for future if someone is still having issue.